# Change Image Border Color Twice onclick

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm trying to change the image border color onclick. First, when a user clicks an image, image border color changes to green and later needs to change to white. Below is my code, please let me know if I'm doing something wrong. It always displays white image border color and never green.

```
<div style="float:left;width:30%;">
 <img id="1" src="/images/37.jpg" width="163" height="100" alt="image not  displayed" onclick="openOnImageClick(this)" />
 <img id="2" src="/images/102.jpg" width="163" height="100" alt="image not displayed" onclick="openOnImageClick(this)" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function openOnImageClick(image)
{
 image.style.border = "3px solid green";

 // Some Ajax processing happens here

 image.style.border = "3px solid white"; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: is it okay if i can give you examples but using jquery version? or you prefer native js

Comment: Hi Boyee..I need to use native js

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/tvf2mgje/

```
<div style="float:left;width:30%;">
     <img id="1" src="/images/37.jpg" width="163" height="100" alt="image not  displayed" onclick="openOnImageClick(this)" />
     <img id="2" src="/images/102.jpg" width="163" height="100" alt="image not displayed" onclick="openOnImageClick(this)" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function openOnImageClick(image)
    {
        image.style.border = "3px solid green";

        // Some Ajax processing happens here

        setTimeout(function change ()
        {
            image.style.border = "3px solid white"
        }, 3000);
    }
</script>
```